# How do I set different widths on scope buttons in UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a little problem and didn't found any solution yet.

I have a `UISearchBar` with a `ScopeBar` in my application. The `ScopeBar` includes 4 scope buttons. All of them have an equal width at the moment.

One of my buttons has a longer text than the others. In my case, the text gets truncated. It looks something like:

```
[  short  |  short  |longte...|  short  ]
```

There would be no problem to show the whole text, if i could minimize the width of the short buttons and add some pixels to the third button.

**First question:**
Is it possible to set different button sizes?

**Second one:**
If yes, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its possible to access the properties of the `UISegmentedControl` (scope bar) directly from the `UISearchBar` using the public APIs.

One way to work around this is to access the `UISegmentedControl` is to use a private property of the `UISearchBar`: `_scopeBar`.

A clean way to do so would be to declare a category on `UISearchBar` to expose this property:

```
@interface UISearchBar (ExposeScopeBar)

@property (readonly) UISegmentedControl *_scopeBar;

@end
```

Then all you have to do is access the scope bar (which is a classic `UISegmentedControl`), and set its `apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent` property to true:

```
self.searchBar._scopeBar.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
```

[image: scope bar after modifications]

You could also use the [`-setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW16) method of `UISegmentedControl` if you need more fine-grained control on the segment size.

Keep in mind though that this uses a private UIKit API, and **there's a change your app will be rejected from the App Store**.

---

Another option would be to search recursively for the `UISegmentedControl` in the `UISearchBar` view hierarchy instead of using the private property.

Here's a pseudo code snippet to do this:

```
- (UISegmentedControl *)scopeBarForSearchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    return [self scopeBarInViewHierarchy:searchBar];
}

- (UISegmentedControl *)scopeBarInViewHierarchy:(UIView *)view
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]])
    {
        return view;
    }

    for (UIView *child in [view subviews])
    {
        UIView *result = [self scopeBarInViewHierarchy:child];
        if (result)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

*Again: This is pseudo-code. Untested.*

This solution does not make usage of private APIs, so it should pass the App Store validation without issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the second one, because it's important for my app to be available all the time.
I had to changes something: (UIView *child in [view subviews]). Maybe you could edit your answer and correct this?

Secondly, the Method apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent did not work in my case. I had to give fixed values to the segments.